# Epoch real-time charts - multi layer - Javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, real-time, epoch.js

The below example works to run Epoch in real time , however, what I am trying to do is running multi layer line instead

```
    var barChartData = [{
  label: "Series 1",
  values: [{
    time: getTimeValue(),
    y: getRandomValue()
  },
{
      label: "Series 2",
      values: [{
        time: getTimeValue(),
        y: getRandomValue()
      }

]}, ];
```

of one as below, but I am not sure how to push data for different layers? any help?    I have tried to push the data with the multilayer, but I received an error, and I could not find any hints in the Epoch API documentation? any help would much appreciated

```
///////////////this function generates the date and time in milliseconds//////////

function getTimeValue() {
  var dateBuffer = new Date();
  var Time = dateBuffer.getTime();
  return Time;
}

////////////// this function generates a random value ////////////////////////////
function getRandomValue() {
  var randomValue = Math.random() * 100;
  return randomValue;
}

////////////// this function is used to update the chart values /////////////// 
function updateGraph() {
    var newBarChartData = [{time: getTimeValue(), y:getRandomValue()}];

  barChartInstance.push(newBarChartData);
}

////////////// real time graph generation////////////////////////////////////////     
var barChartData = [{
  label: "Series 1",
  values: [{
    time: getTimeValue(),
    y: getRandomValue()
  }]
}, ];

var barChartInstance = $('#barChart').epoch({
  type: 'time.bar',
  axes: ['right', 'bottom', 'left'],
  data: barChartData
});
```

Html Code below to run the code,

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/d3.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/epoch.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.goldhillcoldtouch.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/epoch.min.css">
</head>

<div id="barChart" class="epoch category10" style="width:320px; height: 240px;"></div>
<p id="updateMessage" onclick="updateGraph()">click me to update chart</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, basically you can push an object of the data with array of values as below...

```
 chart.push([
    { time: time, y: x},
    { time: time, y: x * Math.log(x)},
     { time: time, y: x * Math.pow(Math.log(x), 2)}
 ]);
```